# Any benefits to declare an enum class underlying type bool?

Tags: c++, enums, underlyingtype

In the library I am currently developing, I have this little thing:

```
enum class BoolMode : uint8_t
{
    TrueIfFalse = 0,
    TrueIfTrue  = 1
};
```

This is a tiny helper used to easily produce reversible condition checks, while only having to create a single implementation that's easy to write and to read...

For this helper to be effectively *easy to use*, I had to define the comparison operator for `bool` *(obviously)*. I did it like that:

```
inline constexpr bool operator ==(const bool boolValue, const BoolMode mode) noexcept
{
    return (boolValue == static_cast<const bool>(mode));
}

inline constexpr bool operator !=(const bool boolValue, const BoolMode mode) noexcept
{
    return (boolValue != static_cast<const bool>(mode));
}

inline constexpr bool operator ==(const BoolMode mode, const bool boolValue) noexcept
{
    return (boolValue == static_cast<const bool>(mode));
}

inline constexpr bool operator !=(const BoolMode mode, const bool boolValue) noexcept
{
    return (boolValue != static_cast<const bool>(mode));
}
```

I was wondering if there would have any *benefits* to define `BoolMode` this way:

```
enum class BoolMode : bool
{
    TrueIfFalse = false,
    TrueIfTrue  = true
};
```

As it does not spare the *effort* to have to define the comparison operators anyway, I don't see what the best option would be...

Questions:

- What is the purpose to use `bool` as the underlying type ?
- Is there concrete examples of the use of it ?
- Is there anything in this code to which I should be aware of ?
- Any clues and/or suggestions to improve the code ?

*Thanks in advance.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `bool` is the underlying type of `X`, then `std::underlying_type_t<X>` is `bool`.

Variables of type `bool` and `enum`s with `bool` underlying type only have two valid states; `0` and `1`.

Variables of type `uint8_t` and `enum`s with `uint8_t` underlying type has 256 valid states; `0` through `255`.

Both a compiler, and metaprogramming, can be aware of this difference.  A custom `notstd::optional` could use the fact that `3` is not a valid `bool` to make `notstd::optional<bool>` take up a single byte (its value would be `0` for `false`, `1` for `true` and `3` for `nullopt`).

This could also be used to smart-pack `bool`s or `enum`s with `bool` underlying type into bit-fields when serialized.

In theory, the assembly generated for `==` when `bool` is the underlying type could do a bit comparison instead of zero or non-zero byte check.  I could imagine platforms where that is faster.  Meanwhile, if `uint8_t` was the underlying type, a non-zero value *anywhere* in the enum means it maps to `true` when cast to `bool`.

None of these issues are likely.

Comment: Short, clear and all _true_. Thanks ! +1 and validation... ;) – I didn't think about the serialization _(though this particular `enum` has little chances to get ever serialized)_. I did know about the possible `asm` optimization _(thx)_. For the last bit to be true, an explicit cast of a value that's not defined by the enum would be needed _(which would mean that it would have had been done "on purpose")_, but that's for sure better not to allow such a thing if it's unwanted...